# Не работают некоторые библиотеки на Python 3.10, Mac OS

Tags: python, macos, библиотеки

Некоторые библиотеки после установки все равно не работают. Пытался запускать и через VS code и через IDLE - результата нет, выдает ошибку:
ImportError: No module named watchdog.observer
На такую строчку:
`from watchdog.observer import Observer`
Библиотеку устанавливал через pip3, т.к. по дефолту стоит Python 2.7 на маках.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, это моя какая-то ошибка или дело в другом? Не знаю, поможет ли, но мак на м1. Спасибо!

Comment: Если ставили Python 3.10 отдельно, то устанавливайте библиотеки для него через `pip3.10 install` (не факт что такое будет работать) или `python3.10 -m pip install`. Ну и учтите, что многие библиотеки еще могут быть не обновлены для Python 3.10 и выше.

Comment: Спасибо за оперативный ответ! Попробую. Я просто на самом деле достаточно начинающий пользователь. Логика верна, что для достаточно часто используемых и распространенных библиотек обновление до новых версий Python происходит быстрее, чем для более узконаправленных?

Comment: В целом да. Некоторые библиотеки вообще могут быть в заброшенном состоянии по факту, и не обновиться никогда. Я бы рекомендовал на новую версию переходить как минимум через год после ее выхода (3.10 вышла в октябре 2021, см. https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-3100/).